# Unable to run Spring Cloud Config-Server in Eureka First Bootstrap mode

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

*****Config Server- Application Service Setup*****

1. Below is the configuration from application.yml

   ```
   server:
     port: 8882
   eureka:
     client:
       serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
   spring:
     cloud:
       config:
         server:
            git:uri: https://github.com/appleman/config
   ```
2. Below is the configuration from boostrap.yml

   ```
   spring:
     application:
       name: configserver
   ```
3. Starting of this plain spring boot application registers config-server to Eureka.

**General Eureka Server is running on 8761 port

********Below is the Application Client configuration*****

4. Below is the Application Client configuration in my bootstrap.yml

   ```
   spring:
     application:
       name: contractService,envDEV13 
     cloud:
       config:
       enabled: true
       discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: configserver
   eureka:
     instance:
       nonSecurePort: ${server.port:8080}
     client:
       serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://${eureka.host:localhost}:${eureka.port:8761}/eureka/
   ```
5. Injection of properties in Spring Controller like the below snippet is not working.

   ```
   @Value("${creditService.eppDbUrl}")
   String bar;
   ```

Please suggest us if we are doing anything wrong.

Comment: Why do you have `spring.application.name: contractService,envDEV13`? I don't know how config server will react to that. What are the names of the files in the github? What does `/env` show on the application client?

Comment: spring.application.name: contractService,envDEV13, This will actually load both the property files from github to project during runtime. Names of files in github : contractService.properties, envDEV13.properties. Server itself is not starting up as it is failing to inject variable bar during startup, so cannot invoke /env. Please suggest if you have any insights.